# WMI event alerts

Tags: sql-server, alerts, event-notification

I am trying to understand WMI event alerts and have implemented a mirror with alerts on DATABASE_MIRRORING_STATE_CHANGE such that all database failover if the state is either 7 or 8 (manual failover or automatic)

Yesterday my mirror failed over but the none of the other database failed with it.  This has led me to believe some other state was reached that I am not trapping.

My question is how can I see what events were fired, are they held on a queue somewhere and can this be queried?

Furthermore if they are on a queue and my WQL is looking at this queue waiting for this event, then how often is this queue polled by my query? (or how does this bit work)

Lastly where can I find a list of WMI events that can be used in such event cases?

Thanks

Comment: I can only assume I haven't made myself clear in my questions, can anyone advise if what I have asked makes sense at least?